# Zend Framework 2, InputFilter validate array of value

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

I'm using an InputFilter to validate my data but no Zend\Form.

```
    $entities = new Input('entities');
    $entities->setRequired(false);
    return $entities;
```

Entities is a collection of Entity.

I don't know how to check that entities is a valid array and then that each value of entities is a valid entity.

Answer (score 2):

If your *Entity* is one dimension array, use ArrayInput. if it is a multi-dimension array, which means a collection of array, use CollectionInputFilter.